# Convert 1 to 1 relation in ER to a Table

Tags: database

If we have two entities in an ER model. 
Sport and Organization.

We have a relationship between these two. it is 1 to 1 relationship. 
One sport belongs to one Org. one Org. handles one sport.

If i want to covert this to relations, I will have one Sport relation one ORG. relation. 
How should i create a relation for the 1 to 1 relationship?
1 to many is easy as is many to many.

Comment: 1-1 just means that *one* of the tables has a key to the other (of course the key should be from the "parent"), and the multiplicity of the FK is 1 (the difference between 1-1 and 1-m is the FK multiplicity). Although, it could *also* be implemented as combining both relations it into *one* table without necessarily breaking any normalization - e.g. they are mutually dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a "1 to 1" relationship from ER model to Relational means that you have to create a relation putting a foreign key in either the first table or the second one. You can choose the table that makes more sense to have the foreign key and it will depend on the particular usage.

In these cases, I used to put the foreign key in the table that looks more concrete. For example you could have the foreign key in the sports table. If in the future the requirements changes (you relationship to "1 to N") and it is possible that an organisation could handle several sports, you do not have to change anything as you already have the foreign key in the sports table.